# jQuery slideToggle() overlapping footer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a paragraph that is hidden on my HTML page. When button is clicked it display it through jQuery slideToggle(). However, when I toggle the paragraph it overlaps the footer at the bottom. How do I prevent this and push the footer down as I toggle(show) the paragraph?

`application.js`

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    var contentText = $(this);
$("#paragraph-toggle").slideToggle(1500,"linear", function(){
    if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
        contentText.text("HIDE");
    }else {
        contentText.text("VIEW");
    };
  });
});
```

`index.html`

```
<button>VIEW</button>
<div id="paragraph-toggle">
    <div>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elite</p>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
</footer>
```

Comment: Sounds like  css problem. Need to create demo with enough css to replicate this problem. Html shown won't do that with browser default rules

Comment: You can Hide() n show() footer div. so it will not overlap..like  if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
        contentText.text("HIDE"); $('footerdivId').hide();
    }else {
        contentText.text("VIEW"); $('footerdivId').show();
    };

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a CSS issue where you have elements whose position has been changed by using the position:; property. If you have elements whose position is absolute or fixed (look this up on W3C), they will not affect the flow of the page. You also need to consider z-index's since absolute sits at the highest level, fixed the 2nd highest, relative the 3rd highest and static the lowest.

If you have elements floating on one another in the wrong order, see what position the elements are, if they have overflow settings and what the z-indexes are.

Flow can also be affected by offsets (top/left/right/bottom) and margins (especially so). Play with them in Firebug or Chrome inspector after the animation is complete.

You can also debug the jQuery animate function to see what CSS properties are being set on the element in question while it is being animated. Then you can change styles to override some of the settings that jQuery is applying.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 //application.js
$(".button").click(function(){
var contentText = $(this);
$("#paragraph-toggle").slideToggle(1500,"linear", function(){
if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
    contentText.text("HIDE");
    $("#footerID").hide();  //hide footer when paragraph is shown

}else {
    contentText.text("VIEW");
    $("#footerID").show();// show footer when paragraph is hide
};
 });
});


 Index.html

  <button>VIEW</button>
 <div id="paragraph-toggle">
<div>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elite</p>
</div>
</div>
<footer id="footerID">
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this problem is because only css. Your #paragraph-toggle is should be position :relative instead of position : absolute fixed